# why is $and operator not working in mongodb mongoose when iam trying to fetch stock number through sellerId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

iam using this function to fetch stock Number through sellerId but instead of one record
iam getting all of them.

```
const fetchStock = (req, res) => {

  StockModel.findOne({$and: [{ "productId": req.body.productId._id }, { "sellerId": req.body.sellerId }] })
    .then((stock) => {
      res.json(stock);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json({ Message: "Internal Server Error.", err });
    });
};
```

and as response iam getting

Comment: How it is possible with this function `findOne`, this will return only one document at a time, and have you checked these `req.body.productId._id` and `req.body.sellerId` printing in console?, are you getting this values perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use `$and` here, just do this:

```
const fetchStock = (req, res) => {
  StockModel.findOne({ "productId": req.body.productId._id, "sellerId": req.body.sellerId })
    .then((stock) => {
      res.json(stock);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json({ Message: "Internal Server Error.", err });
    });
};
```

You would only need to use `$and` in situations where, for instance, you're checking two separate conditions on the *same* `age` property, like so:

```
{
  $and: [{ age: { $gt: 2 } }, { age: { $lte: 4 } }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const fetchStock = async (req, res) => {
   try {
      const { productId, sellerId } = req.body;
      let stock = await StockModel.findOne({ "productId": productId._id, "sellerId": sellerId  })
      await res.json(stock);
   } catch (err) {
      res.json({ Message: "Internal Server Error.", err });
   }
}
```

And this cann't be, that `findOne` returns you array of docs, probably you re-write code, but you have forgot to restart the server / refresh the page/ resend the query.